# How to use "with table as" in pyspark sql function?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The code below has an error

```
spark.sql("WITH q AS (SELECT  b.*
                FROM    df \
                WHERE   parent_id = 59 \
                UNION ALL \
                SELECT  d.* \
                FROM    df d \
                JOIN    q \
                ON      d.parent_id = q.id) \
               SELECT * \
               FROM q").show()
```

the error is:

```
AnalysisException: Table or view not found: q; line 1 pos 221;
```

So I need to create a view of 'q', but how?

Comment: Try using triple quotes (```"""```) to enclose the SQL statement.

Comment: Please try this:
spark.sql("WITH q AS (SELECT  b.* FROM df b WHERE parent_id = 59) (SELECT  d.* FROM df d JOIN q ON d.parent_id = q.id) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM q )").show()